# How to randomly pick images and goes it to another empty list?

Tags: jquery, html, css, random, append

I have an unordered list of images with different colors and I want it to randomly pick a 2 images and goes to another list, I know the appendTo and Math.Random will do the trick but I dont know how to implement it can you help me?

Here's the fiddle and code

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul class="imageList">
              <li><img class="swapimage"  src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img class="swapimage"  src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/ffaa00/fff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img class="swapimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/ff00d5/fff" alt=""></li>
              <li><img class="swapimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/30c7db/fff" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul class="randomList">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="main-button" type="button" value="swap" id="swapBtn" name="swapBtn">


$('#swapBtn').on('click', function(){
    $('.swapimage').prependTo('.randomList li');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uw5cvz8z/

Comment: Here's how you would do it with 1 image. https://jsfiddle.net/uw5cvz8z/4/

Comment: I got it for loop worked on multiple images. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

A little late...took this newbie a while. Here is how I would do it:

```js
len = $(".swapimage").length

$('#swapBtn').on('click', function(){
 number = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    do {
     number2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    } while (number2 == number);
    
    $('.randomList li').eq(number).replaceWith( $('.swapimage').eq(number) )
    $('.randomList li').eq(number2).replaceWith( $('.swapimage').eq(number2) )
});
```

```css
.imageList {  margin-bottom: 100px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="main-button" type="button" value="swap" id="swapBtn" name="swapBtn">
  <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="imageList">
                  <li><img class="swapimage"  src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt=""></li>
                  <li><img class="swapimage"  src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/ffaa00/fff" alt=""></li>
                  <li><img class="swapimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/ff00d5/fff" alt=""></li>
                  <li><img class="swapimage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/30c7db/fff" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
    
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="randomList">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uw5cvz8z/6/)